# Dozer - Mapping to a common destination class from two source classes

Tags: java, javabeans, dozer

Here's my scenario. I have three simple classes: SourceClassA, SourceClassB & DestClass. I have two custom converters defined inside the mapping XML in the following way:

```
<mappings>
    <configuration>
        <custom-converters>
            <converter type="com.myproject.ClassAConverter">
                <class-a>com.myproject.SourceClassA</class-a>
                <class-b>com.myproject.DestClass</class-b>
            </converter>

            <converter type="com.myproject.ClassBConverter">
                <class-a>com.myproject.SourceClassB</class-a>
                <class-b>com.myproject.DestClass</class-b>
            </converter>
...
        </custom-converters>
    </configuration>
</mappings>
```

Is this kind of mapping valid at all ? Can we map to the same destination class from two different source classes using custom converters ?

In my case, when I tried this, the ClassBConverter is never invoked at all by Dozer during bean mapping. Any thoughts ?

Comment: That code looks correct to me. Can you write a simple test case to demonstrate this bug?